# Move unique_ptr: reset the source vs. destroy the old object

Tags: c++, move, unique-ptr

My question is about the example in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

```
struct List
{
    struct Node
    {
        int data;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> next;
    };
 
    std::unique_ptr<Node> head;
 
    ~List()
    {
        // destroy list nodes sequentially in a loop, the default destructor
        // would have invoked its `next`'s destructor recursively, which would
        // cause stack overflow for sufficiently large lists.
        while (head)
            head = std::move(head->next);
    }
 
    ...
};
```

When `head = std::move(head->next)`, there are three things happen:

1. reset `head->next` to `nullptr`;
2. set `head` to the new value;
3. destroy the Node object that `head` used to point to;

The above code works means 3 is guaranteed to happen after 1, otherwise the chaining still exists.

I would like to know whether there is a written-down rule to guarantee such order, or it is only a hidden implementation details and the example just works.

Answer (score 7):

> When `head = std::move(head->next)`, there are three things happen:
>
> 1. reset `head->next` to `nullptr`;
> 2. set `head` to the new value;
> 3. destroy the Node object that head used to point to;

Assignment operator in this case should work as if `head.reset(head->next.release())` function is called, as per [[unique.ptr.single.asgn]/3](https://eel.is/c++draft/unique.ptr#single.asgn-3):

> ```cpp
> constexpr unique_ptr& operator=(unique_ptr&& u) noexcept;
> ```
>
> Effects: Calls `reset(u.release())` followed by `get_deleter() = std​::​forward<D>(u.get_deleter())`.

In such an expression `head->next.release()` has to be evaluated first anyway. `reset` performs its work in the following order:

1. Assigns result of `head->next.release()` to the stored pointer
2. Deletes the value the pointer stored previously

This order of operations is as well part of the standard, [[unique.ptr.single.modifiers]/3](https://eel.is/c++draft/unique.ptr#single.modifiers-3):

> ```cpp
> constexpr void reset(pointer p = pointer()) noexcept;
> ```
>
> Effects: Assigns p to the stored pointer, and then, with the old value of the stored pointer, `old_p`, evaluates `if (old_p) get_deleter()(old_p);`

---

Long story short - your understanding is correct and guaranteed by the standard